# Manipulating tags inside reusable cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

From help on SO I managed to come up with this approach for a button inside a cell.

**CellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("buildCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let mapsbut = cell.viewWithTag(912) as! UIButton
    mapsbut.tag = indexPath.row
    mapsbut.addTarget(self, action: "mapsHit:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
```

**ViewController**

```
func mapsHit(sender: UIButton!){

    passBuild = buildings[sender.tag]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("mapSegue2", sender: self)

}
```

What happens now is when I scroll through the Table View I get a fatal error on the line:

```
let mapsbut = cell.viewWithTag(912) as! UIButton
```

with message: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

So, what's happening is, the View Tag changes inside the function, and when I try to reference it in the next cell, `912` has been changed.

To counter this I add this line of code at the end of `mapsHit` function

```
sender.tag = 912
```

But now I need the following condition:

```
if the button isn't clicked, change tag to 912
```

which doesn't seem possible.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Table view cells gets reused. It is very likely that cell that contained button with tag `912` has been reused and tag changed to some other value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your custom cell like this:

**buildingCell**

```
class buildingCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapsbut: UIButton!

}
```

**CellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("buildCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! buildingCell

    cell.mapsbut.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.mapsbut.addTarget(self, action: "mapsHit:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
```

and leave your `mapsHit` function exactly the same.

This way you don't have to worry about the Tag for the initial reference so you won't run into any nil errors!